# How to construct to one dataframe for recommender system

Tags: dataframe, recommendation-engine

Goal: want to build a recommender system that can push knowledge contents to users based on their pass behaviors, something like Powerpoint helper. If a user frequently draws a line/circle, then probably push contents related to “drawing properties” would attract users attentions, resulting in a higher CTR.

Data I have:
User_id
User_behaviors
Frequency
Targets

However, the number of user_id,user_behaviors, frequency and targets are not matched, like here
[image]
[image]

In this case, how can I construct it into one csv?